# How do I map sub-objects using SQLAlchemy in Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

- class `Item` with a `name` (e.g. carrot) - easy to map in sqlalchemy.
- class `Unit` with `name` (e.g. mg), `type` (e.g. weight) and `system` (e.g. imperial). - easy to map in sqlalchemy.
- class `Quantity` with `value` (e.g. 5) and `unit` (pointing to `mg` unit) defined above. - easy to map in sqlalchemy, but I don't want to store these objects because quantity only makes sense when attached to an item.
- class `QuantifiedItem` with `item` (points to an existing `item`, e.g. carrot) and `quantity` (e.g. 5mg).

Using classical mapping, I have a mapping for Item, Unit, QuantifiedItem. It doesn't make sense to store Quantity in a separate table. I don't know how to define mapping for QuantifiedItem. I don't want to flatten the hierarchy (I do other operations on quantity like conversion, etc.). I think this might be doable with hybrid attributes but i am not sure.